# preg_match_all multiple matches and pattern for text between html text

Tags: php, parsing, preg-match-all, multiple-matches

I am using:

```
 preg_match_all("/(.*):\s(.*)\n/i", $email, $matches);
```

to get any 'From:' or 'subject:' etc. Which is all good except that my message doesn't come in as "MESSAGE:". it comes in the $matches array as [1][18] as below:

```
< HTML>
    < HEAD></ HEAD>
    < BODY style="background-color:#ffffff">
        **MY MESSAGE IS HERE**< br>
```

Therefore I need a preg_match_all that will :
1. give me all the from, subject or what have you (which i can keep the current pattern unless you know a better one).
2. Give me the text content that is in between the html tags. 
** Is there anyway I can do this using just one preg_match_all which uses both pattern searches at once?**

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML. Better to use a email parser like this: https://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/ for parsing various segments of your email body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If message reliably looks like that every time, just `strip_tags($message);` or remove the `< HTML>< HEAD>< BODY style="background-color:#ffffff">` and `< br>`. with `str_replace`

It should be noted that this is not necessarily a good idea, especially if the html at the beginning and end change.

edit: slightly more elegant if your message is the same every time;

```
$message = substr($message, 54);
$message = substr($message, 0, strpos($message, "< br>---"));

var_dump($message);
```

Comment: yes it always comes in this way. What would I replace with? just space i guess?

Comment: Replace it with nothing.

Comment: `str_replace($message, '< HTML>< HEAD>< BODY style="background-color:#ffffff">', '');`

Comment: okay now iam just left with :
 MY MESSAGE<br>---<br>Add // to the end of your reply<br>[Sent: 12:49 AM 03/28/2013]<hr><table style="margin


I tried doing this after the str_replace...

$message = str_replace('<HTML><HEAD></HEAD><BODY style="background-color:#ffffff">', '',$message);
$pure_message   = explode('<',$message);

Comment: `$message= substr($message, 0, strpos($message, "<br>---"));` message now equals everything before that first `<br>`.

Comment: the code i had worked with the "explode" function. Your code would probably work too though. Thanks!

Comment: edited to a slightly more elegant version, also, remember to mark answers that helped as answered :)